# Electron app packaged with electron-packager doesnt work on other pc's cause of nfc-pcsc

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, nfc

I have created a working electron app(with vue and nfc-pcsc), so now im tryign to distribute it.

I used electron-packager to package the app winx64(other pc's are 64 bit too!), when I run the executable on the development pc it works when I run it on any other pc in the office it doesnt.

So I started debugging and found out that the NFC-PCSC libary was causing issue's on the other pc's. I found out by outcommenting the mounted and beforedestroyed in my .vue component.(where only nfc-pcsc functionality get handled).

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-card style="margin-top: 25px;">
            <v-card-title>
                <h1 :style="styleHeading">Scan employee card<div :class="getClass()"><span v-if="!nfcReady">un</span>ready</div><v-btn style="float:right;" @click="backdoorLogin()">Backdoor login</v-btn></h1>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text style="text-align: center;">
                <img  id="scan" src="../../assets/nfc-card.png"></img>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
</template>

    <script>
        import {Login, Backdoor} from '../../assets/js/auth.js';
       import {NFC} from 'nfc-pcsc';
        var log = require('electron-log');

        export default {
           data(){
                return {
                nfc: null,
                readers: new Set(),
                    styleHeading : {
                           backgroundColor: 
                           this.$parent.$config.THEME.COLORS.h1Background,
                           color: this.$parent.$config.THEME.COLORS.h1Text
                        },
                nfcReady: false
                }
           },
           created(){
            log.info('created');
           },
           mounted(){
              log.info('Mounted start')

              var nfc = new NFC();
                    nfc.on('reader',reader => {
                this.nfcReady = true;
                this.readers.add(reader);
                        console.log(`${reader.reader.name}  device attached`);
                //if a card is being scanned
                        reader.on('card', card => {
                  //do a login api call to see if an employee has this card uid.
                  Login(card.uid).then((response) => {
                      this.$router.push({name: 'Main'})
                  }).catch(() =>{
                    alert('nope')
                  })
                            console.log(`${reader.reader.name}  card detected`, card);
                        });

                reader.on('error', error => {
                  //console.log(error);
                })
                reader.on('end', () => {
                 this.nfcReady = false;
                });
                    });

              nfc.on('error', error => {
                console.log(error);
              })

              log.info('Mounted end')
            },
            beforeDestroy(){
               // stops listening for new readers and stops listening on all the readers too
              this.nfc.close();

              this.readers.forEach(reader => {
                  reader.close();
              });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I have issues with understanding why it only work on my pc. I already put all devDependencies into dependencies (except electron cause it cant) just to make sure i have all dependencies in the right place, but no success.

Comment: It may be a native dep. Can you try electron-builder ? there is a post install for those deps : electron-builder install-app-deps

Comment: Okay im gonna try

Comment: @JeffProd I ran those 2 things. 


    "pack-win": "electron-builder --win --x64",
    "post-install" : "electron-builder install-app-deps" 

After i can open the elctron app on both machines but now everything is just blank with nothing. Cant find any logs

Comment: @JeffProd just tried packaging it with the electron builder got it workign on my pc once again when dpeloyed to other pc didnt work